# Problema al escribir en el fichero Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, arduino

tengo un arduino que manda valores por el puerto serie, lo que quiero hacer es leer los datos y guardarlos en un fichero .txt pero no me guarda los datos. Me puede ayudar?

```
    import time

try:
    import serial
    arduino = serial.Serial('COM5', baudrate=9600, timeout=1.0)

    # Nota: provocamos un reseteo manual de la placa para leer desde
    # el principio, ver http://stackoverflow.com/a/21082531/554319
    arduino.setDTR(False)
    time.sleep(1)
    arduino.flushInput()
    arduino.setDTR(True)
except (ImportError, serial.SerialException):
    # No hay módulo serial o placa Arduino disponibles
    import io
with arduino:
    while True:
        try:

            # En Python 3 esta función devuelve un objeto bytes, ver
            # http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typebytes    
            f = open ('holamundo.txt','w')            
            line = arduino.readline()
            f.write(line)
            f.close()
            # Con errors='replace' se evitan problemas con bytes erróneos, ver
            # http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode
            # Con end='' se evita un doble salto de línea
            print(line.decode('ascii', errors='replace'), end='')
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("Exiting")
            break
```

Comment: ¿Qué error obtienes? ¿Falla la escritura en fichero o la lectura del arduino? ¿Has probado un `print(line)` después de leerla?

Comment: Falla la escritura en el fichero, el print(line.decode('ascii', errors='replace'), end='') lo hace bien, lo que no hace bien es el f.write(line) pero no me sale ningun error solo que al abrir el fichero no hay nada

Comment: Vale ahora lo he entendido, ahora creo el archivo fuera del bucle y funciona. Pero ahora solo me lo guarda cuando hago ctrl+c, lo que me gustaria es que mientras funcione tambien se guardase, se podria hacer?

Comment: Puedes ponerlo como lo tenías antes, abriendo el fichero y volviendo a cerrarlo en cada iteración del bucle, pero abriéndolo en modo "append", para que en lugar de borrar y sobreescribir, añada a lo que había. Tienes que hacer `open("fichero", "ab")`

Comment: Si esta resuelto, acabo de editar el codigo, el problema era la fora de abrir el archivo. Gracias por l'ayuda!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya que cada vez que pasas por el bucle vuelves a abrir el archivo en modo escritura, lo que hubiera previamente en el mismo será eliminado antes de escribir el nuevo valor.

Por tanto, al salir del bucle el archivo contendrá sólo lo escrito en la última iteración del bucle.

Lo que puedes hacer es abrir el fichero en modo "append" para que las líneas que escribas se añadan a lo que ya había, así:

```
        f = open ('holamundo.txt','ab')            
        line = arduino.readline()
        f.write(line)
        f.close()
```